# Responding to a new position from a current recruiter

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment

A few months ago, I was contacted by a recruiter for a position. I was interviewed and hired within three weeks. My start date is currently a month and a half away, after my graduation date.

Yesterday, I was contacted by the same recruiter (I assume by mass email) for a very similar position for which I'm also qualified, but for about 50% more money. It appears that the positions are in the same department.

Given the previous timeframe, I could probably be hired before my current start date. Do I risk anything by applying to the position, or should I contact my current manager about the opening and see if there is a possibility of me moving into the newly open position? Would it be appropriate to contact the recruiter directly?

Comment: If it is the same department they knew the job was coming up.  If they felt you qualified they would have considered you for the job.  Even if it just came up they would have considered you as a candidate before posting the position.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think it would be worth it to approach your manager. Since you're already on track to become an employee of this company I think it wouldn't come across well that you're applying through the recruiter.

Of course you're taking a risk, but with risk comes reward. Plus you never know what they're going to say. After all, you already passed some interviews, and they decided they liked you, so maybe they will consider you for this other position.